# Change brightness of Image with value from input range slider

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabricJS. When working with image on canvas I want to increase, decrease brightness of image. for that I use checkbox to select brightness effect then show brightness range selector so that user can select value of brightness applied on image. 
Now when I click checkbox brightness of image increase, increase in slider increase brightness but after increase, i change slider downwards to decrease brightness, image not changing back with brightness decrease , it turns white...

HTML Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="image-bright" unchecked> Brightness <br />
<div class="brightValue" style="display:none;"> Value:
<input type="range" id="bright-value" value="0" min="0" max="255" step="1" class="span22">
</div>
```

JS:

```
var imagebright=document.getElementById("image-bright");
    imagebright&&(imagebright.onclick=function(){
    if(this.checked){
        $('.brightValue').show();
        var cimg=canvas.getActiveObject();
        cimg&&"image"===cimg.type&&(
        cimg.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Brightness({brightness: parseInt($('#bright-value').value, 10)})),
        cimg.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)));
     }
     else {
        $('.brightValue').hide();   
        }
    });

    var brightvalue=document.getElementById("bright-value");
    brightvalue.onchange = function(){
        var cimg=canvas.getActiveObject();  
        cimg.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Brightness({brightness: parseInt(this.value, 10)}));
        cimg.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
    };
```

once increase brightness, afterwards decrease of brightness value in slider, not decreasing brightness of image. 
When I uncheck, check Brightness checkbox it increases brightness every time.
upon uncheck the brightness checkbox I want to turn off brightness effect completely i.e. no brightness effect on image. pls guide me where to change the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pushing new filter onto an object on every change.

That's why they all multiply, resulting in higher and higher brightness.

Change this:

```
cimg.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Brightness({brightness: parseInt(this.value, 10)}));
```

to this:

```
cimg.filters[0].brightness = parseInt(this.value, 10);
```

Comment: oh ys slider change working well now :) thx 
nw I need to reset brightness to default while turning off checkbox.
else { $('.brightValue').hide();
/// code here to reset brightness to default /// }